# Extending the object boundary for dragging in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am playing around with a great tutorial from here http://ssun.azurewebsites.net/creating-a-draggable-object-in-d3/. What is the best way to extend the active area of the circle for dragging on click? I see three possible solutions:

1. create a complex object that has two circles, one visible and one invisible, but I am not sure if the invisible circle can be clicked on. Maybe 100% transparent.
2. Extend the active area of the mouse cursor(if that is even possible)
3. Extend the active area of the circle beyond visual part.

   Unfortunately, I do not know how to do any of those things. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like two circle approach but I'd group them in a `g` element.  The dragging then works on the `g` element and the second circle is simply to expand the `g`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script>
    var boxWidth = 600;
    var boxHeight = 400;

    var box = d3.select('body')
      .append('svg')
      .attr('class', 'box')
      .attr('width', boxWidth)
      .attr('height', boxHeight);

    var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
      .on('dragstart', function() {
        circle.style('fill', 'red');
      })
      .on('drag', function() {
        d3.select(this)
          .attr('transform', function(d) {
            return "translate(" + d3.event.x + "," + d3.event.y + ")";
          });
      })
      .on('dragend', function() {
        circle.style('fill', 'black');
      });

    var dragCircles = box.selectAll('.draggableCircle')
      .data([{
        x: (boxWidth / 2),
        y: (boxHeight / 2),
        r: 25
      }])
      .enter()
      .append('g')
      .attr('class', 'draggableCircle')
      .attr('transform', function(d) {
        return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
      })
      .style('cursor', 'crosshair')
      .call(drag);
      
      dragCircles.append("circle")
        .attr('r', function(d){
          return d.r * 3;
        })
        .style('fill', 'transparent');

      var circle = dragCircles.append("circle")
        .attr('r', function(d) {
          return d.r;
        })
        .style('fill', 'black');
      
  </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Also, I would bother you for one more question - if there are multiple circles, and my code gives me the parent object "g" with d3.select(this), how can I reference and change the visible circle from there? Can I reference it as a child of the parent object, and how?

Comment: @CindyAlmighty `this.children` is a collection of the circles inside the `g`, so `d3.select(this.children[1])` would be a selection of the 2nd visible circle.